# Azure Form Recognition Label Tool Docker: Endpoint Not Found

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I would like to ask which Endpoint is the correct one to use as setting on Label Tool.

I have tried several service url on docs, portal, and API sample website. This is my error message and setting screenshot:

[image]

[image]

which endpoint service that I should use?

**UPDATE**

I have tried using endpoint on portal too. But same result. I will try to recreate the instance later.

[image]

***SOLVE***

I recreate the instances and put it into West US 2 region. I think the container is not support for v0.1 preview API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form Recognizer labeling tool requires you to enter your Form Recognizer resource endpoint and key in the project setting – 
•   Form Recognizer Service Uri - Your Form Recognizer endpoint URL.
Ex: https: // formrecognizer-service-name.cognitiveservices.azure.com/

To get started with Form Recognizer please login to the Azure Portal to create a Form Recognizer resource (for v2.0 (preview) please use West US 2 or West Europe regions).Take the endpoint and key from the resource you created and use them in the labeling tool.

Comment: I have tried that too, using name from instance at portal

Comment: Can you please share in which region you created the Form Recognizer.

Comment: I tried using Southeast Asia for v1.0. I tried to recreate and change it into West US 2, and it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint should be in the format:

https://**formrecognizer-service-name**.cognitiveservices.azure.com
where 
formrecognizer-service-name is your service name.

You can also find the endpoint URL in the Quick start of the Form recognizer resource in the azure portal.

Comment: I have tried that too, using name from instance at portal

Answer (score 0):

in the message from Microsoft, there is a sentence:
To get started please login to the Azure Portal using this link (link) to create a Form Recognizer resource.

You should follow that link, create Form Recognizer resource, then in the "quick start" section of the Azure portal, you will see the end point and key.

the end point has a format like:

https: // your-name.cognitiveservices.azure.com/

Comment: I have tried that too, using name from instance at portal

Comment: how did it go?  you could also create a brand new form recognizer resource and give it another try.